# Combobox with dictionary in source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a simple dictionary. I would like to bind i to a combobox and then bind the selected value to another property.

```
private const string CellListPropertyName = "CellList";

    private Dictionary<string, string> _cellList;
    public Dictionary<string, string> CellsList
    {
        get { return _cellList; }
        set
        {
            _cellList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CellListPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

Here is my code :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CellsList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedValuePath="Key" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Conf:ConfProperties.Title}">
```

I have tried a lot of different way but my combobox is always empty (even with ItemTemplates, etc) I checked my dictionary it contains 62 elements.

I have also tried to bind 'SelectedValue' to a property defined in my DataContext, but still doesn't work.

Here is my Context

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ParametersViewModel></viewModel:ParametersViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: Dictionary does not support data binding. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636828/binding-to-a-dictionary-in-silverlight-with-inotifypropertychanged. You can use something similar to ObservableCollection instead of the dictionary.

Comment: I've just saw a mistake ... forgot an 's' >< My combobox is filled now , I'll try to see if binding works, if not I'll try with ObservableCollection. Thanks

Comment: Dr.WPF have a great article about an `ObservableDictionary` here: http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

Comment: binding a Dictionary as ItemsSource works like a charme with WPF. but nevertheless if you want this collection to be dynamic at untime then ObservableCollection and DataTemplate is the better choice

Answer (score 0):

your SelectedValue binding looks a little bit strange.
let us assume that your ParametersViewModel has a Property called MySelectedTitle of type string. then your binding should be:

```
 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MySelectedTitle}"
```

if you want to "save" your selectedvalue not to a property of your current datacontext, you have to update your question please